# Xcode An App ID with Identifier 'xxx.xxx.xxx' is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: ios, xcode

I know this question has been asked before but the answers didn't worked for me. I am trying to add my App ID on developer.apple.com but it doesn't recognize my App ID. I think that the problem is in the difference of the Team ID in Xcode and the App ID Prefix in developer.apple.com. This is the Team ID:

[image]

And this is the App ID Prefix:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is not that you mentioned. You or someone may already created your appID that's why your appID doesn't recognised. So you need to enter different string in developer.apple.com each appID will be unique.

Thanks.